# Convert cell text and filling to VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I was wondering of there is a way to convert cell values and formatting to a macro.
In this example I only need text and the filling of cells.

Im looking for a way to analyse a range of cells to then convert to a marco, some sort of marco recorder but instead of recording it, it should analyse the cells and covert it to a macro.

If I run the recorder im getting this output:

```
Sub Macro3()

    Range("E1,F2,G3,H4,I5,J6,F1:J1,E2:E7,F3:F4,G2:I2").Select
    Range("G2").Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("S1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("T1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Text here"
    Range("E8,F5:F9,G4:G8,E9:E13,H3:M3,J2:N2,K1:P1,H5:H10").Select
    Range("H5").Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("S2").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("T2").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Text here"
    Range("T3").Select
End Sub
```

Im am looking to create the exact same code but not by recording the macro but by pulling the data from an exiting sheet.

Anyone an idea how to do this?

Kind regards

Raphael

Comment: If you are talking about specifying parameters like `Range`, `.Interior parameters`, `Border linestyle`, `Cell Alignment` etc then yes it is possible. However you will still have to write a basic macro to read those parameters and do what the above code is doing.